# System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0

Tags: .net, azure

I have created a console application (.NET v4.5.2/4.6) to receive messages from the Azure service bus into on-premises database using Entity Framework 6. When running the console application, I'm receiving the following error

> Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load
>   file or assembly 'Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Could you please share your thoughts to fix this issue?

Comment: Your error is telling you exactly what the problem is. You're missing the Microsoft.ServiceBus assembly. Have you added it as a reference?

Comment: Yes, It's working good in the local environment. When I run on the console application .exe file as an azure webJob in the web app. This error has always come when I start the webJob manually on the web app.

Comment: I found the solution here, It's a dll reference issue. When I deploy the .exe file I got an issue. But now .exe and along with the supporting dll and reference files are compressed as a .zip format. Finally I deploy the .zip file as a web job. It's working fine now as I expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution here, It's a dll reference issue. When I deploy the .exe file I got an issue. But now .exe and along with the supporting dll and reference files are compressed as a .zip format. Finally I deploy the .zip file as a web job. It's working fine now as I expected.

Answer (score 4):

The error message tells us that the service bus assembly is missing when deployed your project. Please check your property of your assembly. Make sure that the value of Copy Local is true before deployment.

[image]