# Tests for Azure Table Storage using Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Common 9.4.0.2-preview

Tags: c#, azure, testing, asp.net-core-2.0, azure-table-storage

I created a .NET Standard 2.0 class library where I use Azure table storage as it's described here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table-storage-how-to-use-dotnet. Also, I created a .NET Core test project to test my client library. And when I run a simple test I get this:

> > System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client, Version=1.22.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. The system cannot find the file specified.

I tried many things to make it work but this is just waste of time. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

`Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client` package is now **obselete**. Please use `Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB` package instead.

Refer [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client/)

**Nuget Console:**

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core -Version 1.9.1
```

(Or)

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB -Version 2.0.0-preview2
```

See more about this **[System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Could not load file or assembly error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42553662/system-io-filenotfoundexception-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-serv)**